# Amazon MWS Flat File Modify Listing

Tags: flat-file, amazon-mws

I'm trying to find the documentation for how the flat file looks for modifying the quantity of a product on Amazon.

This is what we send at the moment but it would be good to see what the list of headings we can use.

```
SKU | Quantity
000 | 1
```

I'm guessing that this is correct,

```
SKU | Price | Quantity
000 | 9.99  | 1
```

Any links would be welcome.

Amazon's MWS site https://developer.amazonservices.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can get to the full description of the flat file feed specifications to send the flat file in the correct format to the MWS by going to the following URL after you're logged into your sellercentral or mws account.

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html/ref=ag_13461_cont_help?ie=UTF8&itemID=13461&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the scratchpad, this will bring back flat files so you can see how they look.

https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/scratchpad/index.html - UK Version
https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html - General (US) version